# Android Day of Week Calculator

Tags: android

I have created program that calculates day of week when entered date in format "January 7 2000" .Why do I get `NullPointerException` exception when I click button to calculate day of week?

Here is source code of app:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
   private int position;
private String value;
private Button button;
private EditText editText;
private TextView textView1,textView2;
private Spinner spinner_month,spinner_day;
private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

private boolean isValid;
private Date date;

private int inMonth, inDay, inYear;

    static boolean isDateValid(int month, int day, int year)
    {
        boolean validation = true;
        int[] daysInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

        if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        {
            validation = false;
        }

        if (day < 1 || day > daysInMonth[month - 1])
        {
            validation = false;
        }

        if (year < 1700 || year > 3000)
        {
            validation = false;
        }
        return validation;
    }

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_calculate);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_day);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_year);
    spinner_month = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_month);
    spinner_day = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_day);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_year);

    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.months,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_month.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.day,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_day.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0)
        value = "1";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1)
        value = "2";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2)
        value = "3";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3)
        value = "4";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4)
        value = "5";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 5)
        value = "6";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 6)
        value = "7";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 7)
        value = "8";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 8)
        value = "9";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 9)
        value = "10";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 10)
        value = "11";
    if (spinner_month.getSelectedItemPosition() == 11)
        value = "12";

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String dayOfWeek;
            boolean isValid;
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/M/d");
            //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
            String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    String getdate = editText.getText().toString()+ value +
                            spinner_day.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    date = sdf.parse(getdate);
                }
                catch (ParseException ex)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
                isValid = isDateValid(date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), date.getYear());

                if (isValid == false)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uneli ste pogresan datum", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        while (isValid == false);

            dayOfWeek = zellerCalc(date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), date.getYear());

            textView1.setText(dayOfWeek);
        }
    });
}
```

**Logcat:**

> 02-07 12:32:16.349 3049-3049/com.example.pavle.dayofborn
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.example.pavle.dayofborn, PID: 3049
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.pavle.dayofborn.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:230)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
//Line 230: isValid = isDateValid(date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), date.getYear());
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat??It will help to identify the line where the exception is occuring.

Comment: I agree with @Ben , in the stacktrace you'll see the line number that's generating the nullpointer

Comment: The null pointer exception is occurring in the line number 230.What is it?

Comment: isValid = isDateValid(date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), date.getYear());

Comment: @pavlenis1906 could you provide input/output examples, without the GUI, so simply with some String with the format of Date that you expect.

Comment: For example input is: "1 January 2000" and  output should be Saturday !!!

Comment: Where are coming the values ? I see two component used to build the date string ... are you missing one ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the scope.

You have an instance variable

```
private Date date;
```

But you declared an other one in the try catch

```
try
{
    String getdate = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + value
                        + textView2.getText().toString();
    Date date = sdf.parse(getdate);
}
catch (ParseException ex)
{

}
isValid = isDateValid(date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), date.getYear());
```

So once you exit the try catch, the one declare in it (and initialize) doesn't exist, the instance variable is never declared so stay at `null`.

You want to initialise the instance one, so remove the declaration to look like :

```
date = sdf.parse(getdate);
```

PS : Since this can be skip by an exception, you will end up with the same problem you should put `isValid` in the try catch too

---

```
boolean isValid = false;

...

try
{
    String getdate = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + value
                        + textView2.getText().toString();
    date = sdf.parse(getdate);
    isValid = isDateValid(date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), date.getYear());
    if (isValid == false)
    {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uneli ste pogresan datum", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
catch (ParseException ex)
{

}
```

**NOTE : Be careful, `Date` getter are almost all deprecated, you should use the `Calendar.setTime(Date date)` to use the `Calendar.get(int field)` to be safe. Then, in validate, check the value you receive, a Date is not a number of day/month/year from 1/1/0000. Month and day are 0 based, so the first day/month is 0 with `Date`**

Comment: When I place isValid inside try I get: Variable isValid might not have been initialized!!!

Comment: if (isValid == false)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uneli ste pogresan datum", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

Comment: Now when I click button inside app it gets pressed and stays like that and nothing happens!!!

Comment: I get error when for example I enter 1 January 2000 "Unparseable date: "200011"(at offset 6)" !!!

Comment: While I was going through isDateValid method got: month = 100,day = 0,year = 0,validation = false and after that there is error: wrong date entered!!!

Comment: Could you edit the question with the problem. And I think we don't need the `zellerCalc` here (remove it to be more readable). A [mcve] would help to correct your problem. I can't reproduce it with Java since I use a String `"2000/1/11"` and it is working. So I would guess you have a wrong String but for that, it would be nice to have some debug PS : cleaning the comment a bit ;)

Comment: zellerCalc is method which is calculating day of week by input string!!!

Comment: @pavlenis1906 I am done, without a [mcve] provided, this was my last comment. It's been 2hours trying to help you but you can't explain what is wrong.

Comment: With debugger getdate is: 2000/1/1

Comment: @pavlenis1906 Well, you didn't read everything I told you. I said that day/month where 0-based. So you have `day = 0, month=0; year = 100`. So you are receiving a ArrayOutOfBoundException (which you never tell...) because you are doig `daysInMonth[month - 1]`. You need to update every check you are doing because of that. Read the documentation of `Date.getXXX` to see the value they return.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have initialized the variable date.

Try this

```
Date date=new Date();
```

Good luck.

Comment: Date date = new Date();
                    String getdate = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + value
                            + textView2.getText().toString();
                    date = sdf.parse(getdate);

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: You were close, the variable is initialized, but not the good one ;) you can see it is done with the parser. Check my answer for more information